# How to scroll to the end of the flatlist without onContentSizeChange

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a requirement where

Flatlist has ListHeaderComponent that must be visible upon Flatlist rendering.

And once user start adding items to the Flatlist, it must be scrolled to the end.

If I use onContentSizeChange, Flatlist will be scrolled to the bottom since data is dynamically getting loaded.

If I get ref from the Flatlist and use FlatList's scrollToEnd method upon data update, FlatList will be scrolled to one item above the end. I think this is happening because data update -> scroll -> flatlist item rendering in order.

Question 1.

Is there a way to prevent scroll to the bottom on initial rendering with onContentSizeChange?

Question 2.

Is there a way to listen on onContentSizeChange event with ref?

Question 3.

Is there a way to wait until rendering actually happen then scroll to the end without onContentSizeChange?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will be better you show the code but still if  you to scroll till end give scrollview `- flex:1` above flatlist or give your flatlist some padding or Add `style={{flex: 1}}` for each View element who is a parent for FlatList.